# Show holdings as of a certain date in quicken on mac?

Tags: quicken, macos

I have Quicken 2015 for OS X.  I wish to see what the account holdings were as of a date two years ago (to reconcile old statements).  On the windows version of Quicken, in the investment view, there is a box into which I can enter the date for which I wish to see the holdings.

How do I see the account holdings as of a certain date on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://qlc.intuit.com/questions/1029963-how-does-one-view-the-portfolio-as-of-a-certain-date-in-q2015-mac-in-q2007-there-was-a-field-top-center-for-entering-a-date-into-i-see-no-such-interface-in-q2015) says the feature does not exist as of 11 months ago.  I think it doesn't exist now either.  That sucks.

Comment: If you consider it important, contact the publisher and say so. If more people do so, it's far more likely to be considered as a possible addition in future versions.